# Principled bsdf Subsurface is causing weird white dots in cycles render mode

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

[image]As soon as I enable the Subsurface in the *Principled BSDF*, it's just painting a lot of mostly white, small dots on the mesh, no matter what color I use as subsurface color. I tried changing all the parameters but it didn't help.
It works just fine with Eevee for some reason but not with Cycles. The mesh is made out of a nurbs path and modelled to look like hair. Any help is appreciated.
Edit: Im using a subsurface radius of 0.5

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello ! Could you add a screenshot of the problem ? Remember that subsurface values are supposed to be in meters (or blender units) so you should use very low values to get a realistic effect. Make sure your object is to-scale, too.

Comment: @Gorgious Hi, thanks for your help. I have added two pictures; one with subsurface and the other without. Additionally, I have included a picture of the Principled BSDF. Im using a subsurface radius of 0.5.

Comment: What do you mean `Im using a subsurface radius of 0.5`? You put 0.5 on all three channels? Default is `1`:`0.2`:`0.1`. Also the SS value is more often around `0.03`, definitely never `0.1`, that's ten times too much. Why do you use SSS for hair ?

Comment: @Gorgious Well, I guess I don't really have to use it, but I'm just wondering why it's not working. Changing the values isn't doing anything noticeable.

Comment: Well my first comment still stands. A real hair strand is fractions of a millimiter in diameter. here you are setting a subsurface value of 100 millimeters ! You should read a bit on how subsurface scattering works

Comment: @Gorgious I wasn't able to find anything that could help. Would you be able to suggest something? And as said, changing any of the values isnt having much effect

Comment: It looks like your hair doesn't have any thickness. Subsurface works with objects that have volume (AFAIK)

Comment: @Gorgious Do you know a method for adding thickness? The Solidify modifier isn't helping. Also, why does it seem to work with Eevee? I've noticed it seems to work with the Christensen-Burley mode too. Could you please explain that a little? I can't seem to find informations about it. And thanks!

Comment: Eevee doesn't actually simulate the light rays going through matter, it's just using an approximation. I don't know the details but like all the effects of Eevee, it's most likely based on very smart approximations that imitate reality. Cycles on the other hand is physically based, and it uses real formulaes that have been published in scientific papers to simulate light going through space and matter